# Doesn't update the value on the screen

Tags: c#, acumatica

I use this code for get the new value for the product, but i want to see  this one on the screen, i used:

”row.UnitPrice”,  but the data is there, but no on the screen. 
So i need to call some another funtion for update it?

```
protected void SOLine_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

        var row = (SOLine)e.Row;

        row.UnitPrice = null;

        if (row.OrderType == "SO")
        {
            if (row.InventoryID != null)
            {
                InventoryItem oItem = PXSelect<InventoryItem,Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID,Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), row.InventoryID);

                if (oItem != null)
                {
                    decimal? qty = row.Qty;
                    row.UnitPrice = CalcLinePrice( oItem.RecPrice,qty);

                    Base.Transactions.Update(row);

                }
            }
        }

    }

protected decimal? CalcLinePrice(decimal? unitPrice, decimal? qty) 
{
        return unitPrice *2 * (qty);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `yourGrid.View.RequestRefresh()` after you update the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Hybridzz: you should update CuryUnitPrice field instead of UnitPrice. Also it's necessary to use PXCache.SetValueExt method to raise all field-level handlers for the CuryUnitPrice field when assigning new value:

```
sender.SetValueExt<SOLine.curyUnitPrice>(e.Row, price);
```

On a side note:

1. you should never invoke `Update` method for currently processed record in FieldUpdated handlers - `Base.Transactions.Update(row);` must go away
2. static PXSelectorAttribute.Select method must be used to retrieve InventoryItem selected for SOLine record:

   - the PXSelectorAttribute stores records in single GlobalCache storage shared among all user sessions: it's a more efficient option in comparison to QueryCache of the PXView class accessible only for 1 user
   - reduce maintenance costs as you don't need to update BQL queries in multiple places if someone change BQL query for the SOLine.InventoryItem field

Answer (score 1):

The 'Unit Price' column in the Details grid is associated with the field CuryUnitPrice and not the UnitPrice.

So you might need to update the correct DAC field.

```
row.CuryUnitPrice = CalcLinePrice( oItem.RecPrice,qty);
```